# Manually add shared Windows printer in macOS

Tags: macos, network, windows, printing, smb

In OS X one could [manually add a printer using the Advanced tab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12111/trouble-browsing-windows-network-printers-from-mac) of the printer system preferences dialog with an smb address.

How can I manually add a printer in macOS now that the tab is gone?

[image: advanced print tab removed in macos]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the advanced tab by right clicking just to the left of the word Add, selecting `Customize Toolbar`, and dragging the advanced tab onto the tool bar.

Comment: Minor clarification - it's the "Add" in the title bar you right-click near, not the "Add" button on the lower left of the same window.  It took me a few minutes to figure out that distinction.

Comment: To "right-click" hold down control and click.

Answer (score 3):

As a review, here are the steps to add a Windows shared printer:

1. Open **System Preferences - Printers & Scanners**. Click the lock to unlock this preferences pane.
2. Press the + button at the bottom of the printer list.
3. Click Windows at the top of the new popup
4. Navigate through the menu tree to find the windows shared printer you want. You may have to enter the computer's username and password to access it.
5. Using the new popup menu, choose the appropriate printer software. If you printer is not listed, choose the closest match. (Make sure you match the color/black and white property)
6. Click Add.

---

If that doesn't work, then **[this apple support article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25395?locale=en_GB)** says that all **compatible**, windows shared printers appear in this list. Here's the excerpt:

> If you can’t add the Windows printer you want, the printer software your Mac has for it may not support printing to a shared Windows computer. Update the printer software on your Mac, or ask your network administrator for help. For more information, see Update or change printer software.

---

#### Sidenotes

You *can* still add printers the following ways:

- AirPrint
- IPP (Internet Printing Protocol)
- LPD (Linear Printer Daemon)
- HP Jetdirect - Socket

All of these connection options can be found under the IP tab in the Add Printers window.

Comment: Thanks, this way will work if the auto-discovery is functioning well. There used to be an advanced tab that would let you specify the location of the printer if it wasn't.